# How do I print an entire Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a csv file which I am reading using Pandas. I want to print the entire dataframe so that I can check which columns are of `string` data type, because I want to apply `pd.to_numeric()` function to such columns to convert them into `float` data type. 
The dataframe is only 156x30,so printing it in it's entirety should not be much of a problem. I checked [dataframe.values method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) but there is no parameter I can specify to do this directly. Following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_ = pd.read_csv("path/to/csvfile")
file_.values
```

which returns:

```
array([[1991, 'Berlin', 4.8, ..., '25,428.00', 4.8, nan],
   [1992, 'Berlin', 5.0, ..., '32,054.00', 5.0, nan],
   [1993, 'Berlin', 5.3, ..., '22,193.00', 5.3, nan],
   ..., 
   [2014, 'Stuttgart', 4.8, ..., '103,027.00', 4.8, nan],
   [2015, 'Stuttgart', 4.4, ..., '110,668.00', 4.4, nan],
   [2016, 'Stuttgart', 3.9, ..., '108,562.00', 3.9, nan]], dtype=object)
```

I want to print this dataframe in it's entirety. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: This might be a duplicate, but it is a much better posed question than the other one.